# Return number of coins needed of the coin at that position in an array format

Tags: python, algorithm, list, function

I am trying to return the number of coins in an array needed for the sum of a number.

So if m is 143 and coin = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1], it will return [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1] meaning no 200-coins, one 100-coin, no 50-coins, two 20-coins, no 10-coins, no 5-coins, one 2-coin and one 1-coin.

Right now my solution returns 5, which is the count of coins.

```
        def coinSplit(m):
            if m == 0:
                return 0
            for i in range(len(coin)):
                if coin[i] <= m:
                    return 1 + coinSplit(m-coin[i])

      coin = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
      print(coinSplit(143))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following iterative implementation works:

```
def coinSplit(m):
    res = []
    for c in coin:
        num = m // c
        m = m % c
        res.append(num)
    return res

>>> coinSplit(143)
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

This assumes a coin pool for which this greedy approach always yields a result.
If you want this to be recursive, you can try:

```
def coinSplit(m, coins):
    if m == 0:
        return [0 for coin in coins]
    return [m // coins[0]] + coinSplit(m % coins[0], coins[1:])

>>> coinSplit(143, [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1])
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: `num, m = divmod(m, c)`

Comment: Wow! Great answer. I suppose this is a usual question for you. For me it's a thing to learn.

Comment: @WalterTross True, but for the beginner level, I prefer to be explicit with the basic operators.

Comment: the [Style Guide for Python Code (PEP 8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends: “Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.” This means that the name of the function should be `coin_split`

Comment: @WalterTross I agree. But I will stick to the OP's naming if you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind. My remark was more for the OP than for you

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the arithmetic operators in python. Specifically division `/` and modulus '%'

Get the quotient and remainder by iterating through the list until the remainder is zero.

coin = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]

for example:

- 143/200 = 0; 143 % 200 = 143
- Move on to the next one, 143/100 = 1; 143 % 100 = 43

repeat that process till the remainder is zero

Answer (score 0):

You are returning number of total coins needed, disregard of their value. You need to keep track of number of each coin which I assume you want to create a list as the same size of your input (`coin = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]`) and initialize it with zeros, and as other answer, add to the right index using the modulus and then return this list. You can still write it as recursion but have another operation to add the right index.

I think this is like a homework, so I am not providing the code for you. I hope this helps.